# Custom criteria for kmeans in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I would like to run a clustering algorithm in scikit-learn and use it in a standard pipeline (i.e., I need to write it in . For this clustering algorithm, I would like to run kmeans `N` times (i.e., with `N` different initial points), and then use my own function to choose the best run. The currently implemented version of kmeans has a built in way to run with `N` iterations and to choose the best based on minimized within-cluster variances. Essentially I want to copy this kmeans function, but use a different criteria for the "best" fit.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. A promising approach seems to be to write my own estimator (e.g., using the tools at https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/project-template/). It seems that this estimator would need to implement `fit`, `fit_predict`, `fit_transform`, `get_params`, `predict`, `score`, `set_params`, and `transform`. In my mind, this estimator could just run kmeans `N` times internally, then return the single best centroid fit per my criteria.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using *inheritance*?

You can do OOP in Python. So you'd override only the outer loop of the sklearn KMeans class, and inherit everything else.